# UICollectionView and UINavigationController not cooperating — cells occluded by nav controller on setting prompt

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, autolayout

In my UIViewContoller's subclass, ViewWillAppear asks whether or not there's any data to present, and if there is, changes the UINavigationController's prompt accordingly. This triggers an animation as the prompt pops into view, causing the UINavigationBar to grow in size. When this happens it partially occludes the cells in the top row of the UICollectionView.

I have a vertical Auto Layout constraint of 0, seemingly pinning the UICollectionView to its nearest neighbor, which should be its superview, but the navbar still blocks the top halves of the cells. I've tried everything — telling the CollectionView to layout its subviews, reloading data, etc., but nothing seems to work. Any idea what's going wrong?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if(self.orderedURLSet.count == 0){
    self.navigationItem.prompt = nil;
    [self.collectionView setNeedsDisplay];
} else {
    self.navigationItem.prompt = @"Tap photos to edit";
}
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [self.collectionView layoutSubviews];
}
```

**Edit:** What makes this even stranger is that when I rotate orientation the collectionViewCells aren't occluded, and the full cells remain visible when I rotate back to portrait orientation. Is there some way I can "trick" my app into thinking its layout has changed and it needs to reposition the cells? LayoutSubviews isn't doing the trick.

**Edit:** After digging a little more into the UIView documentation, it looks like setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded are really the methods I should be using, and not `layoutSubviews`. I've tried calling both of them, on `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried??

```
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return YES;
}
```